# Как сделать программу мультиязычной?

Tags: c#, winforms, локализация, интернационализация

В программе буквально 10-20 строк которые нужно переводить? Каким образом сделать?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вы можете посмотреть на [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y99d1cd3(v=vs.100).aspx) пошаговую инструкцию которая объясняет, как это сделать.

Если коротко, то вам нужно воспользоваться менеджером ресурсов:

```
ResourceManager LocRM = new ResourceManager("WindowsApplication1.WinFormStrings",typeof(Form1).Assembly);
// вызов нужной локализации строки:
MessageBox.Show(LocRM.GetString("strMessage"));
```

ResourceManager [документация](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.resources.resourcemanager(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: на мсдн на английском всё(

Comment: @jokelocker добавил в ответ ссылку на русскоязычное описание класса ResourceManager. Там так же есть вся необходимая информация. А вообще, без знания английского в программирование можно не соваться даже.

Comment: я сунулся пока нормально